ASP.NET MVC HttpContext.User custom object works locally and in IIS but, when deployed to App Service is null
This is in the HttpModule:
public void Init(HttpApplication application) 
{
    _httpApplication = application; 
    _httpApplication.AuthenticateRequest += OnAuthenticateRequest; 
}

public void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
     _customclass.Process(_httpApplication.Context);
}

In the _customClass process method:
private HttpContext _context;

public void Process(HttpContext context)
{ 
    _context = context; 
    var authenticationTicket = GetCurrentAuthenticationTicket();

    if (authenticationTicket == null)
    { 
        var userEmail = GetEmail(); 
        CreatePrincipalAndSetAsCurrentUser(userEmail); 
        authenticationCookie =   CreateAuthTicket(   CustomIdentityObject); 
       _context.Response.AppendCookie(authenticationCookie); 
    } 
    else if (authenticationTicket.Expired) 
    { 
        RedirectAndEndResponse("~/Logout.aspx"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        CreatePrincipalAndSetAsCurrentUser(authenticationTicket); 
    } 
} 

CreatePrincipalAndSetAsCurrentUser:
private ICustomPrincipal CustomPrincipal 
{
    get { return _context.User as ICustomPrincipal ; } 
    set { _context.User = value; } 
}

When we try to access HttpContext.Current.User as ICustomPrincipal, the application is throwing this error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

As mentioned above, this works fine in local and also in IIS; the issue only happens in Azure App Service. I tried to create custom principal in PostAuthenticateRequest but the application is behaving weird.

What is the framework  version of your App?

Did you configurae Authentation in Azure AD?

Its an ASP.Net MVC 5 application. Yes, we are able to get email from AD and one other auth provider which we use to create the custom principal

Which .NET Framework version 4.** ?

Check PostAuthenticateRequest once.

.Net Version Asp.Net v4.8

We tried creating prinicpal in PostAuthenticateRequest but the application is not working as expected.  When its works locally and on IIS, why not in App Service?

Is your App getting authenticated correctly and are you able to login?

Auth is working as expected using AD and other Auth provider also.

Ok.. need to check it once

There are many places in your code that null reference exceptions can occur, so merely sharing the code above is not enough. "this works fine in local and also in IIS" is irrelevant to this question as Azure App Service isn't your local environment. You might want to hire a consultant and share all the code with them, or switch to Azure VM where you can host on IIS.

We dubbed the code and its failing only when trying to get the HttpContext.Current.User. No other null exception in the current code base.

With below solution, we get username as email in AD but, with external auth, its returning  actual name of the user, which we cannot use to create principal.

Even I got the same error with your code.
I am able to retrieve the Username with the below CustomPrincipal.
My CustomPrincipal.cs
using System.Security.Principal;

public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
{
    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
    public string User { get; private set; }

    public CustomPrincipal(string UName)
    {
        Identity = new GenericIdentity(UName);
        User = UName;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

My Global.asax file:
 protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string username = null;
     if (HttpContext.Current != null)
     {

         if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
         {
             username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
         }

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
         {
             HttpContext.Current.User = new CustomPrincipal(username);
         }
     }
 }

Output:

